# SQL Select distinct COL1 where COL2 is _ and COL2 IS NEVER _?

Tags: sql, distinct

(Using Oracle SQLDeveloper)
I need to generate a SQL statement that will find the distinct number of colors where the shape is a square but never a circle.

The table below is titled:  MYOBJECTS

Currently my SQL statement (which is imcomplete) is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COLOR, SHAPE FROM MYOBJECTS WHERE ((SHAPE = 'square') AND (..........));
```

[image]

FYI the answer should be:

**COLOR**  |  **SHAPE**
yellow  | square
brown   | square

Can anyone help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . One method is two levels of aggregation.  Another would use subqueries:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT COLOR)
FROM MYOBJECTS o
WHERE SHAPE = 'square' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM MYOBJECTS o2
                  WHERE o2.color = o.color AND o2.SHAPE = 'circle'
                 );
```

EDIT:

Oh, I notice that you want the individual rows, not the count:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COLOR, SHAPE
FROM MYOBJECTS o
WHERE SHAPE = 'square' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM MYOBJECTS o2
                  WHERE o2.color = o.color AND o2.SHAPE = 'circle'
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

The other `group by` answer is incorrect, but mental exercise for what it would take to do it with group by...

`SELECT color FROM MYOBJECTS GROUP BY color HAVING SUM(shape = 'square') > 0 AND SUM(shape = 'circle') = 0`

Answer (score 0):

i think you just need `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT COLOR, SHAPE
FROM MYOBJECTS
WHERE SHAPE = 'square'
GROUP BY COLOR
```